# Четвёртая цифра в правах доступа

Tags: unix

```
$ chmod 0777 файл-или-каталог
```

Что означает **0** перед остальными цифрами?

Comment: Восьмеричную систему исчисления. Для chmod не обязательно указывать.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду 0х для 16 и 0 для 8 ?

Comment: Ага____________

Answer (score 6, accepted):

согласно [документации](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Numeric-Modes.html#Numeric-Modes) (этот топик можно просмотреть при наличии установленного пакета *gnu/info* командой `info 'file permissions' 'numeric modes'`) числовые значения обозначают:

```
Value in  Corresponding
Mode      Mode Bit

          Other users not in the file's group:
   1      Execute/search
   2      Write
   4      Read

          Other users in the file's group:
  10      Execute/search
  20      Write
  40      Read

          The file's owner:
 100      Execute/search
 200      Write
 400      Read

          Special mode bits:
1000      Restricted deletion flag or sticky bit
2000      Set group ID on execution
4000      Set user ID on execution
```

т.е., `0` в числе `0777` обозначает: убрать все три «специальных» бита — sticky-bit, setguid-bit и setuid-bit.

---

чтобы меньше «ломать себе голову» над всем этими циферками, удобнее, вероятно, использовать [символические эквиваленты](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Symbolic-Modes.html#Symbolic-Modes) (`info 'file permissions' 'symbolic modes'`).

например, вышеприведённую команду `chmod 0777 файл-или-каталог` можно заменить такой командой:

```
$ chmod a=rwx,a-st файл-или-каталог
```

- `a` — для «всех» (комбинация из `u` — пользователь, `g` — группа, и `o` — остальные).
- `=` — установить именно такой набор битов.
- `a=rwx` — установить биты `r` — чтения, `w` — записи, и `x` — исполнения, для «всех».
- `-` — убрать перечисленные биты.
- `a-st` — убрать «специальные биты». эквивалентно `u-s,g-s,-t`

Answer (score 3):

Устанавливает В '0' биты Запуск от от имени пользователя и группы (set user or group ID on execution) и 'липкий' бит (restricted deletion flag or sticky bit).

Answer (score 1):

Биты четвёртой тройки означают

04000 - (s-бит) выполнение с правами владельца файла. При выполнении    данного файла система заменит эффективный пользовательский    идентификатор (euid) на идентификатор владельца файла. При    необходимости программа может вернуться к пользовательским правам с    помощью вызова `seteuid(getuid())`. Команда `ls -l` этот бит показывает как 's' вместо 'x' для владельца или 'S', если владельцу нет разрешения исполнять файл. **В Linux** для каталогов, скриптов и прочих    файлов этот бит игнорируется. **Во FreeBSD** (совместно со специальной опцией монтирования) для каталогов этот бит указывает, что новые файлы будут наследовать владельца от каталога, а не от euid создавшей программы, а новые подкаталоги кроме того так же будут наследовать и этот бит.

02000 - аналогичный s-бит для группы-владельца файла. **В Linux**    этот бит так же используется совместно с запретом исполнения группе    для включения обязательных блокировок ([man 2 fcntl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html)), а для    каталогов указывает, что новые файлы будут наследовать    группу-владельца от каталога, а новые подкаталоги кроме того так же    будут наследовать и этот бит.

01000 - (t-бит) в старых unix-системах ставился для часто    используемых программ сохраняя их образ в оперативной памяти после    исполнения. В настоящее время **в Linux и FreeBSD** этот бит указывает, что в данном каталоге, несмотря на доступность каталога на запись какому-то пользователю, разрешается удалять или создавать жёсткие ссылки только владельцу файла, владельцу каталога или суперпользователю.