# Как правильно выставить права для /var/www/?

Tags: linux, apache2, permissions

Первый случай production сервер, второй для разработки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На продакшене и на сервере разработки должно быть всё одинаково (ИМХО). Оптимально 755 на папки и 644 на файлы - причём овнер: пользователь, под которым крутится апач, это www или www-data обычно.

Comment: если овнер www-data, а я работаю под другим <username>, то как мне редактировать файлы во время разработки?

Comment: Под sudo . sudo -u www-data bash , и ты под пользователем www-data . Дальше редактируешь/сливаешь что хочешь. Как настроить судо - поищи. Ну и конечно лучше разрабатывать на локальном компе, где OpenServer стоит например, заливать всё в git-репу, а на сервере в одну команду git pull (выпонять под sudo) заливать весь проект сразу.

Comment: а если сервер на локальной машине? через sudo каждый раз неудобно .

Comment: Я так понимаю не из консоли править будешь. Тут не подскажу, извини - я для локальных машин с IDE только винду использую. Хотя предположу - что тогда без судо, тогда надо, чтобы апач крутился под твоим пользователем в системе, или чтобы ты мог под ним логиниться - вообщем чтобы тот кто записывает файлы и тот кто апач = один и тот-же овнер.

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте каталогу `chmod 2775` и группу `chown .www-data`.
Теперь новые файлы в этом каталоге будут иметь группу каталога ([подробнее о первой цифре chmod](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529551/130)).
Себя добавьте в группу www-data:

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data.
```

Установите `umask 2`, чтобы новые файлы были автоматически доступны группе. Хотя теперь вы сможете делать файлам в этом каталоге chmod 664 сами без привилегий.

Чтобы задействовалось новое членство в группе нужно войти в систему заново.