# Наследование прав директории linux

Tags: linux, acl

Создаю папку например `/tmp/foo`. Выставляю на неё права `775`. Соответственно для этого выполняю `chmod -R 775 /tmp/foo`. Владельцем делаю пользователя `myuser` и группу `mygroup`: `chown -R myuser:mygroup /tmp/foo`. Это ясно и понятно. Но есть задача: все новые файлы и папки (условно-бесконечная вложенность) внутри `/tmp/foo` должны наследовать от неё владельца и права доступа. Если я создам например файл `/tpm/foo/bar.txt` у него должны быть так-же права `775` и владелец `myuser` группа `mygroup`. Даже если файл создаёт другой пользователь из группы `mygroup`.

Пробовал делать `chmod -R 4775 /tmp/foo` всё равно у создаваемого внутри файла права `755` и владелец `otheruser` группа `otheruser`. Названия юзеров и групп условные. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Каталог монтируемый? Если да, то права необходимо выставлять после монтирования. И права устанавливаются при создании файла/каталога,  к сведению.

Comment: @Adokenai про права после монтирования знаю. Нет, каталог не монтируемый. Он создаётся раз и навсегда. А про права при создании.. не совсем понимаю. mkdir с параметром `-m`? Ну.. ок. А если после создания сделать `chmod` это не то?

Comment: когда права назначены, то для новых каталогов и файлов используются права создателя. То есть от чьего имени было создано, тот и владелец. chmod можно сделать всегда.
P.S. если речь о tmpfs, то там свои заморочки, ибо временный каталог в памяти.

Comment: Это невозможно. Владелец всегда тот, кто создает. Права же ставятся те, которые указаны в umask пользователя.

Comment: см. также
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524139/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0/529551#529551

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Но есть задача: все новые файлы и папки (условно-бесконечная вложенность) внутри /tmp/foo должны наследовать от неё владельца и права доступа.

Если коротко, то наследовать владельца невозможно (без изменений в ядре linux) и по большей части лишено практического смысла. В linux, как и в большинстве unix-подобных ОС, установка бита [`setuid`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suid#setuid_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%85) на каталоге не даёт никакого эффекта — владельцем всегда является создатель файла.

С другой стороны можно наследовать группу файла, для этого используется бит [`setgid`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suid#setuid_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%85):

```
chmod g+s /tmp/foo
```

После этого подкаталоги/файлы будут наследовать группу и бит `setgid`, но права всё же будут [определяться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906780/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B2-linux/906990#answer-906990) [`umask`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/umask)'ом пользовательских процессов. Для того чтобы задать права по умолчанию, можно установить значения «*ACL по-умочанию*» (*default [ACL](https://linux.die.net/man/5/acl)*).

```
setfacl -m d:u::rwx /tmp/foo
setfacl -m d:g::rwx /tmp/foo
```

Эти значения действуют аналогично *~umask* (т.е. дополнению к `umask`'у) в данном каталоге, модифицируя права запрошенные процессом при создании файла/подкаталога. Т.е. любой процесс может запросить создание файла с меньшими правами, но обычно большинство программ пытается создать файл с правами `0666`, а каталоги с `0777`. Эти значения также наследуются подкаталогами.